# how to select same column with different condition?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select data from two tables.
-warehouse has two columns: warehouseId, warehouseName
-transportation has three columns: transporter, warehouseId1, warehouseId2
i want to select from two tables and get warehouseName from table A for warehouseId1 and warehouseId2 
here is my code but it does not work.

```
select a.transporter, b.warehouseName as warehouse1, b.warehouseName as warehouse2
from transportation a, warehouse b
where a.warehouseId1 = b.warehouseId and a.warehouseId2 = b.warehouseId
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `warehouse` twice into `FROM` (just remember to use two different aliases for them):

```
SELECT
    a.transporter,
    b1.warehouseName as warehouse1,
    b2.warehouseName as warehouse2
FROM
    transportation a,
    warehouse b1,
    warehouse b2
WHERE
        a.warehouseId1 = b1.warehouseId
    AND
        a.warehouseId2 = b2.warehouseId
```

or use `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT
    a.transporter,
    b1.warehouseName AS warehouse1,
    b2.warehouseName AS warehouse2
FROM
    transportation a
JOIN
    warehouse b1 ON a.warehouseId1 = b1.warehouseId
JOIN
    warehouse b2 ON a.warehouseId2 = b2.warehouseId
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be clearer to use subselect:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.transporter,
    (SELECT warehouseName FROM warehouse WHERE warehouseId=a.warehouseId1) AS warehouse1,
    (SELECT warehouseName FROM warehouse WHERE warehouseId=a.warehouseId2) AS warehouse2
FROM
    transportation a
```

This will generally use exactly the same query plan as MarcinJuraszek's solutions, but may be a little clearer as to what's going on.

Comment: I have tested your solution and I got this error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Then your `warehouse` table has at least two rows with the same `warehouse.wareHouseId`. Change it to whatever your actual primary key is, or, if you're using some other view or expression where I put `warehouse`, change it to using the actual table that has `wareHouseId` as a primary key.

Comment: I'm not able to change the table now

Comment: If you're still having problems with both of these possible solutions, then my only interpretation is that there are further details in your situation that I would need to see in order to help you. Either submit as a new question, or maybe we can [discuss it in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/229099/17575647-how-to-select-same-column-with-different-condition?tab=general).